# How to Store User Text Input in Code-Behind From XAML WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, code-behind

my question is fairly simple.

As the title states, I would like to know how to store user text entered into a WPF TextBox from XAML as a string element within the code-behind. The concept is that the user enters the text a TextBox, then, upon clicking the "Finished" button, the values in that TextBox are stored in the code-behind as string elements (which may be entered into an array).

---

XAML

```
<Window x:Class = "WpfApplication3.MainWindow" 
xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:local = "clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" 
mc:Ignorable = "d" Title = "MainWindow" Height = "350" Width = "604">
<Grid Background = "White" Margin="0,4,0,-4">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
        <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
        <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
        <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
        <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width = "*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content = "Employee Info" FontSize = "15"
     FontWeight = "Bold" Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "0"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column = "0" Orientation = "Horizontal" Margin="0,38,0,26" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Label Content = "Name"  VerticalAlignment = "Center" Width = "70"/>
        <TextBox Name = "txtName" Text = "Muhammad Ali" VerticalAlignment = "Center"
        Width = "200">
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "1" Orientation = "Horizontal" Margin="0,2,0,62" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Label Content = "ID" VerticalAlignment = "Center" Width = "70"/>
        <TextBox Name = "txtID" Text = "421" VerticalAlignment = "Center"
        Width = "50">
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "1" Orientation = "Horizontal" Margin="0,32" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Label Content = "Age" VerticalAlignment = "Center" Width = "70"/>
        <TextBox Name = "txtAge" Text = "32" VerticalAlignment = "Center"
        Width = "50"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "1" Orientation = "Horizontal" Margin="0,61,0,4" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Label Content = "Position" VerticalAlignment = "Center" Width = "70"/>
        <TextBox Name = "txtPosition" Text = "Programmer" VerticalAlignment = "Center"
        Width = "200"></TextBox>

    </StackPanel>
    <Button Click ="Button_Click" x:Name="button" Content="Finished" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,21,0,0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237"/>

</Grid>
```

CODE-BEHIND

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window


    string EmpName = "blank";
    string EmpID = "blank";
    string EmpAge = "blank";
    string EmpPosition = "blank";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtName = EmpName;   //Here's where I attempt to store the TextBox Information
        txtID = EmpID;
        txtAge = EmpAge;
        txtPosition = EmpPosition;
    }


  }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Have you tried txtName.Text = EmpName? Currently you are changing the whole textbox control, not only the text in it. To Read the data from the gui to your code simply swap those two to get EmpName = txtName.Text. Probably you should look up how assignments and Properties work in C#, that could help your understanding.

Comment: Ah, so it had to be reversed. So simple! Thank you so much!

Comment: Or, just bind the textbox to the property you want to use. You may wish to look for "MVVM in WPF" once you get the basics of assignments and properties.

Answer (score 0):

As CShark wrote, you should do some research about [assignments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_assignment_operators.htm) and other basic language usage as well. Here is the click event handler:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EmpName = txtName.Text;             // Use the Text property to get the (string) value of the entered text.
    EmpID = txtID.Text;                 // The left hand side of the assignment operator gets assigned the right hand side expression.
    EmpAge = txtAge.Text;               
    EmpPosition = txtPosition.Text;
}
```

Please note that a lot of other controls store their value in the Property Content (e.g. Label)